# Magento Slow Front-end

Tags: magento-1.9

Recently I have installed Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 with ShoppyStore theme quick-stater package. Back-end is seems working fine. But front-end is taking too much time to  load a page. I am newbie (not a programmer) and this is my first time on magento. I choosed Magento due to seller account system module.

Can somebody help me to faster my Magento site? or if it is not possible then can someboday tell me is seller account system possible in OpenCart? Here is my site link [beedo.pk](http://www.beedo.pk)

Comment: run Aoe_profiler , and as it default cPanel install or you probably on shared hosting...

Comment: How to run it? I am on VPS and have WHM

Comment: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler , also remove all extra modules from apache.

Answer (score 1):

points are for speed magento:

1. Merge CSS and Javascript files

> Magento admin -> System Configuration -> Developer -> Under
> “Javascript Settings”, change “Merge Javascript Files” to YES.
>
> Magento admin -> System Configuration -> Developer -> Under “CSS Settings”,
> change “Merge CSS Files” to YES

1. Clear cache
2. Enable Flat Catalog
3. Enable the Magento compiler
4. Log cleaning via admin
5. Visit bellow link

http://www.appseconnect.com/speed-up-your-magento-store-from-slow-to-insanely-fast/

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: how exactly your list will help with 15sec TTFB ? hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're struggling with a slow Magento 1 (or Magento 2) here is a checklist I use:

1. You have to find out whether it's TTFB or frontend that's slow. Go to webpagetest.org and run your website through it.
2. If it's TTFB - disable all 3rd-party extensions and switch to a default Magento theme. It should become faster. Then enable extensions one by one and find an abuser. In 99% cases it's a poorly written module that drags you down.
3. If it's frontend that's slow - webpagetest let's you see a waterfall diagram like this: [image]
   See if you can find files that are taking too long to download and execute.